# remove click event on a button

Tags: events, powershell

I'm using a powershell script that also draw a basic interface to simplify some task.
I need to bind a specific click event to a button element, and I'm using this code

```
$button_makeAction.add_Click({
    # my code
})
```

The problem is that, during script execution, I want to bind that button to a different click event. Using the same code it appends another click event and execute both, so I need something like `$button_makeAction.reset_Click` or `$button_makeAction.set_Click` in order to remove the first event code. Is this the correct way?

Answer (score 2):

Register the click-event using `Register-ObjectEvent`. That way, you can find it later and remove it. Example:

```
#Create object and register event
PS C:\> $button = New-Object system.windows.forms.button
$event = Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $button -EventName Click -Action { Write-Host "TestClick" }

#Action is working
PS C:\> $button.PerformClick()

TestClick

#Removing eventsubscriber
PS C:\> Unregister-Event -SubscriptionId $event.id

#Notice no output on next click
PS C:\> $button.PerformClick()
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the method `remove_Click` (`remove_MyEvent` in the example below) and a script block stored in a variable. Here is the example:

```
# A static class with a sample event
Add-Type @'
using System;
public static class TestEvents {
    public static event EventHandler MyEvent;
    public static void InvokeEvent()
    {
        if (MyEvent != null) {
            MyEvent(null, null);
        }
    }
}
'@

# Script used as event handler, it prints "In event handler."
$script = {
    Write-Host "In event handler."
}

# Add the script handler
[TestEvents]::add_MyEvent($script)

# Test: it writes "In event handler."
[TestEvents]::InvokeEvent()

# Remove the script handler
[TestEvents]::remove_MyEvent($script)

# Test: it does not write write "In event handler." because the handler has been removed
[TestEvents]::InvokeEvent()
```

Note that in PS V2 CTP3 there was an issue [713174](https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/713174/v3-ctp2-regression-or-breaking-change-script-block-handlers-are-not-removed-from-events-ditto-with-delegates)
but it seems to be resolved, so that casting to `[EventHandler]` is not even needed. But keep this trick in mind, too.

Answer (score 1):

How about adding an IF statement to the event handler and executing code based on a condition?

Answer (score 1):

You might do something like:

```
$Button.Add_Click({If ($Button.Tag) {Invoke-Command $Button.Tag}})
```

Then set your dynamic event in the tag property like:

```
$Button.Tag = {MyCode}
```